# Troubleshooting Compile making things slower

Tags: performance-tuning

I'm trying to speed up the following piece of code which runs in about 0.5 seconds on my machine.

```
numSteps = 5;
numSamples = 10000;
b = 2;
d = 2;

step = Function[{Typed[w, "Real32"]},
   Module[{X}, X = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {b, d}]; 
    w - .1 X\[Transpose] . X . w]
   ];
batchStep = Function[{Typed[wb, "Real32"]}, step /@ wb];

wb0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {numSamples, d}];
NestList[batchStep, wb0, numSteps]; // Timing
```

Using `FunctionCompile` fails with `Cannot find a definition for RandomVariate`. Meanwhile, using Compile below makes it run in about 1 second. What are the tips to troubleshoot this?

```
numSteps = 20;
numSamples = 10000;
b = 2;
d = 2;

step = Compile[{{w, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{X}, X = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {b, d}]; 
    w - .1 X\[Transpose] . X . w]
   ];
batchStep = Compile[{{wb, _Real, 2}}, step /@ wb];

wb0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {numSamples, d}];
NestList[batchStep, wb0, numSteps]; // Timing
```

**Summarizing lessons on slow Compile**

- Huge penalty for modifying global variable from inside compiled function, use `Module` to localize variables
- Get better performance for pre-generating random data and threading over corresponding lists, instead of generating on-demand from inside the compiled function
- matrix multiplication for small matrices inefficient, can hand-code solution like in `Henrik Schumacher` solution below

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no point in compiling `RandomVariate` as its backend is already compiled. Putting it into `Compile` just leads to some call from the `CompiledFunction` to the *Mathematica* kernel -- which just adds overhead without providing any advantages. What you could do instead is compile the loop generated `NestList`:

```
cApplyNested = Compile[{{X, _Real, 3}, {w, _Real, 1}},
   
   Block[{m, n, w1, w2, result, X11, X12, X21, X22},
    m = Dimensions[X][[1]];
    result = Table[0., {m + 1}, {2}];
    result[[1, 1]] = w1 = Compile`GetElement[w, 1];
    result[[1, 2]] = w2 = Compile`GetElement[w, 2];
    Do[
     X11 = Compile`GetElement[X, j, 1, 1];
     X12 = Compile`GetElement[X, j, 1, 2];
     X21 = Compile`GetElement[X, j, 2, 1];
     X22 = Compile`GetElement[X, j, 2, 2];
     result[[j + 1, 1]] = w1 = w1 - 0.1 (w1 (X11 X11 + X21 X21) + w2 (X11 X12 + X21 X22));
     result[[j + 1, 2]] = w2 = w2 - 0.1 (w1 (X11 X12 + X21 X22) + w2 (X12 X12 + X22 X22));
     , {j, 1, m}];
    result
    ],
   
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Now you can generate all samples *first* and then thread `cf` over this data in parallel like this:

```
Xlist = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {numSamples, numSteps, b, d}];
wb0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {numSamples, d}];
result = cApplyNested[Xlist, wb0];
```

On my machine this takes about `0.016409` seconds for `numSamples = 10000` and `numSteps = 20`, while OP's original code takes `1.13243` seconds.

**Edit**

If you want to be a bit more flexible, you can employ *Mathematica* to symbolically generate the code. Then you can employ `Compile` as a JIT-compiler to create a function for each `d` you need (and only if and when you need it). This could be done as follows:

```
ClearAll[cApplyNested];
cApplyNested[d_] := cApplyNested[d] = Block[{XX, X, j, w, ww, code},
    XX = Table[Compile`GetElement[X, j, k, l], {k, 1, d}, {l, 1, d}];
    ww = Table[Compile`GetElement[w, k], {k, 1, d}];
With[{code = ww - 0.1 XX\[Transpose] . XX . ww, dim = d},
 Compile[{{X, _Real, 3}, {w0, _Real, 1}},
  
  Block[{m, w, result},
   m = Dimensions[X][[1]];
   result = Table[0., {m + 1}, {dim}];
   w = Table[0., {dim}];
   
   result[[1]] = w = w0;
   
   Do[result[[j + 1]] = w = code;, {j, 1, m}];

   result
   ],
  
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ]
 ]
];
```

Now you can do

```
numSteps = 20;
numSamples = 10000;
d = 2;

Xlist = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {numSamples, numSteps, d, d}];
wb0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {numSamples, d}];
result = cApplyNested[d][Xlist, wb0];
```

without any severe performance degression. The only thing that you will observe is that call `cApplyNested[d]` for the first time will require some extra time for compilation process. But since we use memoization here, the time of the next call `cApplyNested[d]` the `CompiledFunction` will be already known.

Comment: ok, that's a big speed-up .... I'm surprised that you are hardcoding matrix multiplication for `d=2`, wondering if that's really necessary...this hardcoding reduces utility of this function

Comment: The `Dot` operations for matrices and vectors use BLAS routines and those routines are notoriously slow for small matrix sizes (because they were designed for large matrix sizes). So it does make quite a lot of sense to use hand-coded routines, in particular because one can completely unroll the loops if the sizes are known at compile time.

Comment: I suspect a bug in that code, `cf` is missing. If I use `cApplyNested` instead of `cf` I get the wrong shape out

Comment: Oh I see. `m = Dimensions[X][[2]];` should have been `m = Dimensions[X][[1]];`. Now  it should work as expected.

Comment: thanks, works as expected now, summarizing high-level lessons in question for posterity